# How to parse kubectl describe output and get the required field value

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to fetch Nodeport from a specific pod using kubectl describe command. I came to know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464518/how-to-format-the-output-of-kubectl-describe-to-json) that -o option doesn't work with describe, hence I am trying with following way but I am not getting required value, can someone correct me.

```
kubectl -n core describe svc/pg-debug
Name:                     pg-debug
Namespace:                core
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=postgresql-default
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       172.17.17.19
Port:                     <unset>  5432/TCP
TargetPort:               5432/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  24918/TCP
Endpoints:                172.16.90.10:5432
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Following is the command that i am trying to get the value `"24918"`

```
kubectl -n core describe svc/pg-debug | grep NodePort |awk -F:  '/nodePort/{gsub(/ /,"",$2)}'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use following command to get nodePort from service

```
kubectl get svc pg-debug -n core -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[].nodePort}'
```

Refs:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/
- and see also: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/25