# How to format the output in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I want to get specific output for a command like getting the nodeports and loadbalancer of a service. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far (that didn't work or was showing undesired output)? Hav you tried `kubectl describe svc your-service-name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is pretty lacking on what exactly wants to be retrieved from Kubernetes but I think I can provide a good baseline.

When you use Kubernetes, you are most probably using `kubectl` to interact with `kubeapi-server`.

Some of the commands you can use to retrieve the information from the cluster:

- `$ kubectl get RESOURCE --namespace NAMESPACE RESOURCE_NAME`
- `$ kubectl describe RESOURCE --namespace NAMESPACE RESOURCE_NAME`

---

#### Example:

Let's assume that you have a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` (I've redacted some output to be more readable):

- `$ kubectl get service nginx -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.2.151.123
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30531
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: A.B.C.D
```

Getting a `nodePort` from this output could be done like this:

- `kubectl get svc nginx -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[].nodePort}'`

```sh
30531
```

Getting a `loadBalancer IP` from this output could be done like this:

- `kubectl get svc nginx -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"`

```
A.B.C.D
```

You can also use `kubectl` with `custom-columns`:

- `kubectl get service -o=custom-columns=NAME:metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP`

```sh
NAME         IP
kubernetes   10.2.0.1
nginx        10.2.151.123
```

---

There are a lot of possible ways to retrieve data with `kubectl` which you can read more by following the:

- `kubectl get --help`:

> -o, --output='': Output format. One of:
> json|yaml|wide|name|custom-columns=...|custom-columns-file=...|go-template=...|go-template-file=...|jsonpath=...|jsonpath-file=...
> See [custom columns](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/#custom-columns), [golang template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview) and [jsonpath template](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath).

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Kubectl: Cheatsheet: Formatting output](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#formatting-output)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Kubectl: Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/)*
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes client: Python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)* - if you would like to retrieve this information with Python
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: How to parse kubectl describe output and get the required field value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669973/12257134)*

Comment: Thanks ! this was exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract just single values, perhaps as part of scripts, then what you are searching for is `-ojsonpath` such as this example:

```
kubectl get svc service-name -ojsonpath='{.spec.ports[0].port}'
```

which will extract jus the value of the first port listed into the service **specs**.

docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

---

If you want to extract the whole definition of an object, such as a service, then what you are searching for is `-oyaml` such as this example:

```
kubectl get svc service-name -oyaml
```

which will output the whole service definition, all in yaml format.

---

If you want to get a more user-friendly description of a resource, such as a service, then you are searching for a describe command, such as this example:

```
kubectl describe svc service-name
```

---

docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#output-options