# Can we display only a specific part of output from kubectl describe command in azure pipeline logs?

Tags: azure, shell, ansible, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm creating an ansible task and using shell to execute kubectl describe node nodename command, and I want to display only a specific part of that output in azure pipeline logs. How I can achieve this?

By executing the kubectl describe node nodename getting the entire output but want to display only a specific part.

Comment: Please check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669696/how-to-parse-kubectl-describe-output-and-get-the-required-field-value) helps.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl describe` doesn't support `-o` or equivalent parameters which can be used in `kubectl get...`, it provides a human-readable output and does not support structured output formats like JSON or YAML, please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464518/how-to-format-the-output-of-kubectl-describe-to-json) for the details.

To extract part from the command output, you can use `grep` and `awk` commands in shell. Eg: `kubectl describe node nodename | grep Capacity -A 6`, it outputs 6 lines in the Capacity.