# kubectl - format the resource quota values in json format

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubectl

One way to get the resource quota values in kubernetes is to use the following command

```
>kubectl describe resourcequotas
Name:                   default-quota
Namespace:              my-namespace
Resource                Used     Hard
--------                ----     ----
configmaps              19       100
limits.cpu              13810m   18
limits.memory           25890Mi  36Gi
```

But issue is this display all the values in text file format. Anyone knows how I can get in json format!

Of course, I can parse the output and get the individual entry and construct the json.

```
kubectl describe quota  | grep limits.cpu | awk '{print $2}'
13810m
```

But I am looking for something inbuilt or some quick way of doing it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format the output of kubectl describe to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464518/how-to-format-the-output-of-kubectl-describe-to-json)

Comment: Yes, I saw this. But this is not what I am looking for. thanks for pointing it.

Comment: You can use 'kubectl get resourcequotas -o json', I assume it is not sufficient for your use case -  please explain what you want to achieve and why that does not work for you

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your messages. Let me answer my own question, I have found one.

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) has solved my problem.

**To get the Max limit of resources in json format**

```
kubectl get quota -ojson | jq -r .items[].status.hard
```

**To get the Current usage of resources in json format**

```
kubectl get quota -ojson | jq -r .items[].status.used
```

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl` itself provides a mechanism to provide jsonpath using `-o jsonpath` option. One of the main issues that I initially faced was with respect to having `dot(.)` in `key`. eg., `limits.cpu`.
This issue can be solved by using the expression `"limits\.cpu"` (escaping dot)

```
kubectl get resourcequota -o jsonpath={.items[*].spec.hard."limits\.cpu"}
```